# How do lifetimes and variables captured by closures interact?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, closures, lifetime

I'm currently learning Rust from the the book ['The Rust Programming Language'](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book) and seemingly I've encountered the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("Hello");
    let mut add_suffix = || s.push_str(" world");
    println!("{s}");
    add_suffix();
}
```

results in the compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
3 |     let mut add_suffix = || s.push_str(" world");
  |                          -- - first borrow occurs due to use of `s` in closure
  |                          |
  |                          mutable borrow occurs here
4 |     println!("{s}");
  |                ^ immutable borrow occurs here
5 |     add_suffix();
  |     ---------- mutable borrow later used here
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What I've understood is that `add_suffix` somehow took a mutable reference to `s` (I know that `push_str` requires a mutable reference) and thus increases the lifetime of `add_suffix` to start on the closure definition and ends on the call.

But I don't seem to understand why is that happening before we call the closure (namely `add_suffix`), why does Rust enforce that and what's unsafe about that? If we imagine the lifetime of that mutable reference starts and ends on the the call I can't see a way where that go wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with lifetimes. As you can see in the compiler errors, lifetimes are not mentioned at all. Instead, this is a simple case of "cannot mutate **and** alias simultaneously". I won't delve into the specific reasons; the TLDR is "data race". Here's some useful reading if you are interested in the "why": [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html), [Mutable aliasing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49174630/5637701).

In your example, when the closure is defined and stored in a variable, it has already captured `s` by mutable reference. This means until the mutable reference to `s` is released (a.k.a. until `add_suffix` goes out of scope, after line 5 in your snippet), there can exist no other references (because mutable reference is exclusive). Hence you cannot borrow `s` on line 4.

Comment: Appreciated, I'm already into the Rust book, but what I'm seemingly don't understand is why defining a closure captures the variable in the first place.

Comment: This is not about data races, which can only occur in concurrent code. There are quite a few other reasons why Rust has its reference aliasing rules.